# "On the sunny afternoon" or "On a sunny afternoon?"

Tags: grammar

Which is more correct:

On the sunny afternoon of my tenth birthday,...

or

On a sunny afternoon of my tenth birthday,...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is correct, since your birthday was a single day and you are referring to *the sunny afternoon* of that day.

If, for example, you were talking about your tenth summer then you would use *a sunny afternoon* to refer to one particular afternoon of the many summer days.

Comment: "A sunny afternoon" can also be used to talk about repeated or habitual actions. For instance "I will often sit in the garden on a sunny afternoon".

Comment: Your first sentence is too broad—and actually wrong in some constructions. For instance, we would say: *It was* ***a*** *sunny afternoon* ***on*** *my tenth birthday*. In that sentence, you do *not* want to use the definite article—even though everything you said at first is still true. (It was a single day, etc.)